# Problem with a complex fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm having trouble with this series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}i+2\dot{\theta}\right)\alpha^ne^{in\theta} + \overline{\left(\frac{\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}i+2\dot{\theta}\right)\alpha^ne^{in\theta}} = - \dot{\theta}.
$$

$\alpha$ is complex but $\theta$ is not.

I'd like to find an expression for $\dot{\alpha}$, my fourier series knowledge is a little rusty, so if anyone would give a hint, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is it with these dots?

Comment: The terms are time dependent, but it's of less importance, it was just to differentiate the two $\alpha$'s

Comment: I've edited your question to (hopefully) make clear what was meant by your notation.  If my edit is incorrect, please roll it back, and re-edit your question to clarify.

Comment: It looks correct to me, thanks.

Comment: Something plus its cc is also $2\Re(it)$.

Comment: $2\mathrm{Re}\left(\left(\frac{\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}i+2\dot{\theta}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha^ne^{in\theta}\right) = - \dot{\theta}.
$

Comment: Well, just do the geometric series ...

Comment: $2\mathrm{Re}\left(\left(\frac{\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}i+2\dot{\theta}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha^ne^{in\theta}\right) = 2\mathrm{Re}\left(\left(\frac{\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}i+2\dot{\theta}\right)\frac{-e^{i\theta}\alpha}{e^{i\theta}\alpha-1}\right) = - \dot{\theta}.
$

Comment: Assuming $\theta$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we get: $(\frac{2\dot{\alpha}}{\alpha}+4\dot{\theta})\frac{e^{i\theta}\alpha}{e^{i\theta}\alpha-1}=\dot{\theta}.$

Comment: And when $\alpha$ is not? I'm looking for an expression for $\dot{\alpha}$ and I can't break $\alpha$ up, so I'm not so sure if this is the right approach.